# Windows 10 upgrade shows "Restoring your previous version of Windows" when at 100%

Tags: windows

Today I've got my reserved copy of Windows 10 Pro, tried to download and install it, twice, from Windows Update application, and both times installation goes up to 100% and then - "Restoring your previous version of Windows" screen appear. When my old Windows 8.1 Pro boots, Windows Update window is showed and it says that the latest update failed, and error code is 8007002C. Can anybody tell me what I'm supposed to do? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Here you go: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows/windows-update-error-80070002#1TC=windows-7

Comment: [try this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-error-80070002#1TC=windows-7) then try again.  You can also just download the .ISO and upgrade that way.

Answer (score 1):

If Windows update keeps failing, you can download the OS image from : 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

This tool allows you to either :

- Upgrade your current windows installation to windows 10
- Create a bootable media to install/repair windows 10
- Download an ISO for a specified version of windows 10